# wordpress div to align like a gallery

Tags: css, wordpress, html

I am not sure what i can do to fix it but I am unable to use css to align the images in 1 row and then another row like a gallery. Can anyone help. I have tried to float the div entry to left and still unable to get it correct.

here is the css for entry

```
 .entry {
clear: both;
margin: 0;
padding-top: 1px;
 }
```

Comment: Here is tiny url to see site  

http://tinyurl.com/bkp6t88

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
display:inline-block
```

to your div class .wp caption

See this article http://designshack.net/articles/css/whats-the-deal-with-display-inline-block/ as there may be some issues with Cross Browser but i think its only IE6, maybe 7

so in your case

```
.wp-caption {
 border: 1px solid #a87c31;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #10050B;
 padding-top: 4px;
 margin: 10px;
 display: inline-block; 
 }
```

Comment: Brilliant. I been messing with this for a bit. I have never had to use inline block before. Thanks for teaching me something today.